# What does .decode('utf-8') mean when scraping csv from website?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, utf-8

I'm currently working on scraping a simple csv file from the UK Government website (https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/) and have written a script that runs successfully, using some help from Stackoverflow.

However, there is one part of code that I don't fully understand in the template I used. **What is the purpose of the .decode() function below?** I know it has something to do with the language of text on a website but not sure why I need it here. This is the first part of the code

```
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd

# Locate URL of csv file
CSV_URL = 'https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/downloads/csv/coronavirus-cases_latest.csv'

# Use requests to scrape and decode csv 

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    list_str = decoded_content.splitlines()

    cr = csv.reader(list_str, delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
```

After this I just put it into a dataframe and do some cleaning.

PS. Please explain in fairly simple terms as I'm not a Python expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers deal with text as a series of bytes. *Anything* in a computer is a series of bytes. Readable text is a special case of bytes where the bytes represent readable characters.

In Python (3), you have two data types: `bytes` and `str`. `bytes` represents an arbitrary series of bytes, `str` represents readable text.

To convert from `bytes` to `str`, you use `.decode` to interpret the `bytes` using a specific encoding like UTF-8, which will yield a `str` with readable characters. The other way around you can `.encode` a `str` to `bytes` using a specific encoding.

`s.get(...)` here apparently returns raw `bytes`, which you need to decode to text.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a specific reason why we use utf-8? Or is that just the most commonly used type?

Comment: Because the data presumably is encoded in UTF-8. If it wasn't, the decoding would—possibly—fail, or at least give you gobbledygook text. UTF-8 in general is a widely used encoding, since it's versatile in the amount of characters it can encode while being space efficient and backwards compatible with ASCII.